# Extension of complex functions to make it holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

I have written my final exam in complex analysis last month but I am not quite satisfied with how my professor graded my exam.

I am in the process of petitioning for regrade. I would really appreciate it if you could help me take a look why I am getting the mark I got OR if you think I should be receiving a higher grade.

Question: Consider the function $$f(z) = \frac{z^3 + 2z^2}{z^4 -1}$$. Define the extension of function f so that it becomes a holomorphic function $f: C(hat) -> C(hat)$.

My solution: Note that $$ z^4 - 1 = (z^2 + 1)(z^2 - 1) => z = +/- i, +/- 1 => z = i,-i,1,-1

See that f: C{i,-i,1,-1} -> C is holomorphic => f: C -> C is meromorphic with poles at z = i, -i, 1, -1

So we an extend the function by defining f: C(hat) -> C(hat) such that
f(i) = infinity, f(-i) = infinity, f(1) = infinity, f(-1) = infinity.

Professor then added f(infinity) = ? But I thought from we only need to perform treatments on the poles? Why is x = infinity a concern here?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: The _domain_ of the extension should be $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$, and thus include $\infty$. In addition to defining the value as $\infty$ at the poles in $\mathbb{C}$, you also must give the value of the extension at $\infty$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Hello Daniel, does that mean f(inf) = inf? Thanks!

Comment: Look at your function. What is $\lim\limits_{z\to \infty} f(z)$?

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid your professor was right, there. As long as we only consider finite complex values, the function is meromorphic, has a pole at $z=1$. To remedy that, we can add the point $\infty$, making the complex plane a sphere (Riemann sphere). But that's not only about adding that point to the set of values of a function, it's also about adding it to the set of arguments. Obviously, we'd have $f(\infty)=0$, but you'd still have to show it's analytic, there. Meaning you can express it as a power series in $1/z$, and that's elementary. But you didn't show that.